# Python priority queue, erase current queue on priority 1 being received?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, priority-queue

I'm utilising a FIFO queue to render text on a VFD display to avoid screen corruption when rendering a combination of "pop up" messages and menus. This works very well, except when I want to render a menu while a message is scrolling I have to wait for the message to complete its scroll.

Is there a way I can utilise a priority queue to "interrupt" the scrolling message and empty the queue of anything else so nothing gets rendered immediately after? ie. if something arrives in the queue with a priority of 1, empty the queue then continue as normal.

```
class RpiLCDMenu(BaseMenu):
def __init__(self, pin_rs=26, pin_e=19, pins_db=[13, 6, 5, 21], GPIO=None, scrolling_menu=False):
    """
    Initialize menu
    """
    self.lcd_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
    self.scrolling_menu = scrolling_menu

    self.pin_rs = pin_rs
    self.pin_e = pin_e
    self.pins_db = pins_db
    self.GPIO = GPIO

    # turn-on the worker thread
    threading.Thread(target=self.lcd_queue_processor).start()


def lcd_queue_processor(self):
    # print("queue started")
    self.lcd = RpiLCDHwd(self.pin_rs, self.pin_e, self.pins_db, self.GPIO)
    self.lcd.initDisplay()
    # clear it once in case of corruption
    self.clearDisplay()
    # self.message('Initialising')

    while True:
        items = self.lcd_queue.get()
        func = items[0]
        args = items[1:]
        func(*args)

self.lcd_queue.put((lcd_render, fixed_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised I actually have no need to have a priority system at all and can just clear the queue before each message or menu is sent to the display.

```
q = Queue.Queue()
with q.mutex:
    q.queue.clear()
```